# License key library for C# windows application that is open source / free

Tags: c#, .net, copy-protection, license-key

Any recommendations for an open source (free) C# library/application for a C# Windows Application that could be used for: (a) creating license/product keys and (b) has library that can be used within the code to perform a check to see whether the entered license key is valid?

(I've seen other posts which cover commercial products, but here I'm looking for a ready-to-go tool with library that can be used in a C# windows application)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Licensing System for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132943/licensing-system-for-net)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The .NET framework has a built-in licensing model [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe8b1eh9.aspx).

See also [*Applications Licensing using the .NET Framework*](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3074001/Applications-Licensing-using-the-NET-Framework.htm) on Developer.com

Answer (score 10):

What about [rhino-licensing](http://github.com/ayende/rhino-licensing)? Here is an introductory license: [Rhino Licensing](http://jagregory.com/writings/rhino-licensing/)

Comment: just having a look now - no obvious tutorials or doco I've see so far?  Perhaps just download source and look at test cases?

Comment: This is exactly what I need - free, no server/client communication required, simple, effective